# Detecting when an application is being uninstalled in Windows

Tags: c#, java, c++, air

I have Adobe Air application that stores at user's machine sqlite files and different shared objects.The problem is that when a user runs application's uninstaller it doesn't remove that data.Adobe Air allows writing of native plugins using C++,C# ,Java etc.I would like to have a plugin that detects when this application is being uninstalled and cleanup the leftovers for it.Is there an easy way to do such a think with one of the afore mentioned languages? Thanks .

PS:To the Dude that voted -2 in my previous version -> Can you next time leave a comment why you have done it ,and what is my fault ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can create a native application that knows how to install/uninstall the AIR application (using arh utility). The whole process is not easy at all, in order to do that you need to obtain approval from Adobe - read this [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/redist/WS485a42d56cd19641-70d979a8124ef20a34b-8000.html) about redistribution and using the arh utility.

Comment: "
I think that you can create a native application that knows how to install/uninstall the AIR application" -that is what I am up to...

Comment: Yes I did.ARH is of little help here.It allows to distribute Air runtime installer with your apps.It can detect installed AIR apps and /re-install/uninstall those.But it doesn't erase the local store directory which I am concerned with and is not capable to target it during uninstall.So still I need a direction how to write a 3 party plugin (probably using win32) that can detect uninstall process for an app ,recognize that it is Air and clean up all that is left after it.